# How to group year from object with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to create a new object in JavaScript to group year. It will store the data into the year group.

The data I have right now:

```
{
    "8": {
        "date": "2016-02-26",
        "value": "0.89000"
    },
    "7": {
        "date": "2017-02-27",
        "value": "0.94000"
    },
    "6": {
        "date": "2017-06-01",
        "value": "0.94000"
    },
    "5": {
        "date": "2017-08-30",
        "value": "0.94000"
    },
    "4": {
        "date": "2017-11-30",
        "value": "1.01000"
    },
    "3": {
        "date": "2018-02-28",
        "value": "1.01000"
    },
    "2": {
        "date": "2018-06-01",
        "value": "1.01000"
    },
    "1": {
        "date": "2018-08-31",
        "value": "1.01000"
    },
    "0": {
        "date": "2018-11-30",
        "value": "1.16000"
    }
}
```

I would like to convert to something like:

```
{
    2016: [
            {
                "date": "2016-02-26",
                "value": "0.89000"
            }
    ],
    2017: [
            {
                "date": "2017-02-27",
                "value": "0.94000"
            },
            {
                "date": "2017-06-01",
                "value": "0.94000"
            },
            {
                "date": "2017-06-01",
                "value": "0.94000"
            }, 
            {
                "date": "2017-08-30",
                "value": "0.94000"
            }
    ],
    2018: [
            {
                "date": "2018-02-27",
                "value": "0.104000"
            },
            {
                "date": "2018-06-01",
                "value": "1.01000"
            },
            {
                "date": "2018-08-31",
                "value": "1.01000"
            }, 
            {
                "date": "2018-11-30",
                "value": "1.16000"
            }
    ]
}
```

Some more content for the purpose to post the question here. Some more content for the purpose to post the question here. Some more content for the purpose to post the question here. Some more content for the purpose to post the question here. Some more content for the purpose to post the question here.

Comment: Playing the devil's advocate, why do you want this?

Comment: anything you have tried so far which you can share here ?

Comment: You are looking for `sorted` dates inside of the year groups? Your code seems to relate that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Object.values` to convert the object into an array. Use `reduce` to loop thru the array and summarize it into an object. Use `substring(0, 4)` to get the first 4 characters of the date string.

```js
var obj = {"0":{"date":"2018-11-30","value":"1.16000"},"1":{"date":"2018-08-31","value":"1.01000"},"2":{"date":"2018-06-01","value":"1.01000"},"3":{"date":"2018-02-28","value":"1.01000"},"4":{"date":"2017-11-30","value":"1.01000"},"5":{"date":"2017-08-30","value":"0.94000"},"6":{"date":"2017-06-01","value":"0.94000"},"7":{"date":"2017-02-27","value":"0.94000"},"8":{"date":"2016-02-26","value":"0.89000"}}

var result = Object.values(obj).reduce((c, v) => {
  var y = v.date.substring(0, 4);
  (c[y] = c[y] || []).push(v);
  return c;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Code:

```js
const data = {"8": {"date": "2016-02-26","value": "0.89000"},"7": {"date": "2017-02-27","value": "0.94000"},"6": {"date": "2017-06-01","value": "0.94000"},"5": {"date": "2017-08-30","value": "0.94000"},"4": {"date": "2017-11-30","value": "1.01000"},"3": {"date": "2018-02-28","value": "1.01000"},"2": {"date": "2018-06-01","value": "1.01000"},"1": {"date": "2018-08-31","value": "1.01000"},"0": {"date": "2018-11-30","value": "1.16000"}};
const result = Object.values(data).reduce((a, {date, value}) => {
  const year = date.slice(0, 4);
  a[year] = a[year] || [];
  a[year].push({date, value});
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `reduce` with `Object.values`:

```js
const data = {"0":{"date":"2018-11-30","value":"1.16000"},"1":{"date":"2018-08-31","value":"1.01000"},"2":{"date":"2018-06-01","value":"1.01000"},"3":{"date":"2018-02-28","value":"1.01000"},"4":{"date":"2017-11-30","value":"1.01000"},"5":{"date":"2017-08-30","value":"0.94000"},"6":{"date":"2017-06-01","value":"0.94000"},"7":{"date":"2017-02-27","value":"0.94000"},"8":{"date":"2016-02-26","value":"0.89000"}};

const res = Object.values(data).reduce((acc, { date, value }) => {
  let [year] = date.split("-");
  (acc[year] = acc[year] || []).push({ date, value });
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

ES5 syntax:

```js
var data = {"0":{"date":"2018-11-30","value":"1.16000"},"1":{"date":"2018-08-31","value":"1.01000"},"2":{"date":"2018-06-01","value":"1.01000"},"3":{"date":"2018-02-28","value":"1.01000"},"4":{"date":"2017-11-30","value":"1.01000"},"5":{"date":"2017-08-30","value":"0.94000"},"6":{"date":"2017-06-01","value":"0.94000"},"7":{"date":"2017-02-27","value":"0.94000"},"8":{"date":"2016-02-26","value":"0.89000"}};

var res = Object.keys(data).map(function(key) {
  return data[key];
}).reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  var year = curr.date.split("-")[0];
  (acc[year] = acc[year] || []).push(year);
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a single [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and you can [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) before the `reduce` to get the desired sorted output:

```js
var data = { "8": { "date": "2016-02-26", "value": "0.89000" }, "7": { "date": "2017-02-27", "value": "0.94000" }, "6": { "date": "2017-06-01", "value": "0.94000" }, "5": { "date": "2017-08-30", "value": "0.94000" }, "4": { "date": "2017-11-30", "value": "1.01000" }, "3": { "date": "2018-02-28", "value": "1.01000" }, "2": { "date": "2018-06-01", "value": "1.01000" }, "1": { "date": "2018-08-31", "value": "1.01000" }, "0": { "date": "2018-11-30", "value": "1.16000" } }

let sortedInput = Object.values(data).sort((a,b) => new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date))

let result = sortedInput.reduce((r, {date, value}, i, a) => {
  let key = date.split('-')[0]
  r[key] = r[key] || []
  r[key].push({date, value})
  return r
}, {})

console.log(result)
```